# AWS Lambda execute shell npm install error

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, shell, npm, aws-lambda

I'm trying to build a web app in AWS lambda and upload it to an S3 bucket. For that, I utilize child process, which is working fine locally.

```
exec('cd /tmp/ && npm ci && ng build --prod="true"', (error, stderr, stdout) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return reject(error);
        }
      });
```

I also tried using npm install instead of npm ci, in all cases it fails with the error:

> "npm ERR! errno -30",
> "npm ERR! rofs EROFS: read-only file system, mkdir '/home/sbx_user1051'",
> "npm ERR! rofs Often virtualized file systems, or other file systems",
> "npm ERR! rofs that don't support symlinks, give this error.",
> "npm ERR! code EROFS",
> "npm ERR! syscall mkdir",
>
> Command failed: cd /tmp/ && npm ci && ng build --prod="true"\nnpm ERR! code EROFS\nnpm ERR! syscall mkdir\nnpm ERR! path /home/sbx_user1051\nnpm ERR! errno -30\nnpm ERR! rofs EROFS: read-only file system, mkdir '/home/sbx_user1051'\nnpm ERR! rofs Often virtualized file systems, or other file systems\nnpm ERR! rofs that don't support symlinks, give this error.\nnpm ERR!

I understand that only the /tmp/ directory is writable in AWS Lambda. I just don't know how to tell npm to run in /tmp.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Hi I've successfully got `npm` working by setting `NPM_CONFIG_CACHE` environment variable to `/tmp/.npm`.

Like this:

```
  const dir = '/tmp/your_project_dir';
  process.env.NPM_CONFIG_CACHE = '/tmp/.npm';
  
  execSync(`npm ci && npm run build`, {cwd: dir});
```

An example Lambda function is [here](https://github.com/tmokmss/deploy-time-build/blob/7836abf3476e18c07b9209f3c4d24d1c8a07b2bd/lambda/nodejs-build/index.ts)

Note that as far as I tested, it seems we cannot use npm in Node 16 runtime. In Node 14 or Node 18 runtime, we can use it without problem.

Also I found someone created a Lambda layer containing `npm` cli which can be used in non-nodejs Lambda environment.
https://github.com/sambaiz/npm-lambda-layer

Comment: Thanks for this answer, this is the key!  I had a containerized Lambda that kept failing to perform its task (`next build && next export`) even though I copy all the files over to the `/tmp` directory before running any commands.  It turns out the `.npm` cache folder was trying to be written to the home folder.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, people install everything during the build phase and then they zip it and deploy as a lambda function. AWS provides some example projects for doing exactly that https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-nodejs.html

Or with amplify https://aws.amazon.com/amplify/

With node there is also an option to use serverless
https://stackify.com/aws-lambda-with-node-js-a-complete-getting-started-guide/

Or, now, you may also consider using docker https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-for-aws-lambda-container-image-support/

Any of this can be prepared in a CI/CD pipeline (https://www.weave.works/blog/what-cicd-tool-should-i-use).

Generally, I would avoid self-modifying lambdas. That's hardly repeatable. One day one npm package will not be available for a minute, AWS will scale out your lambda and it will start failing and your whole application will crumble.

If your goal is to repeatedly build node apps in a lambda go the docker path, that has the most flexibility.

Comment: I do know how to deploy my node project. What I dont know is how to execute a npm command inside the lambda function, since the function is just timing out wihtout an error

Comment: well, my idea was that if you do it as a docker you can better debug what is going on. As I have written previously: What you are trying to do, may not be a good solution, even if it works. But I am absolutely fine with you doing it anyway. If you run npm from node let you consider using a pipe instead of exec https://www.codingwithjesse.com/blog/how-to-use-node-streams-and-how-not-to/ and then run npm in the debug mode https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug-level and log everything line by line. You may get an insight in what is exactly going on.